# How can I be doing anything wrong in this code?

Tags: html, image

just starting HTML and I'm at the point of learning . I know that if I put the "index.html" and the img in the same directory, It should be fine to just address the img by name as in ". But when I open the page, all I see is a cracked image. When I look the preview of the page in my file explorer, it just says that "some images where blocked to avoid the sender identifies your computer. Open this item to exibit the images".  WHen I try to just source with an URL, it shows up fine, no problems at all, I've tried using alt and not, other browsers as well.

I tried renaming the img file to something simpler to simplify not mistaking the name, tried putting the img and the project (index) file in another directory together, and I was hoping to understand why this which sounds so simple is getting me so many errors.

Comment: take the [tour] read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

After searching a bit I came across this hope it helps :)

"Well I think I've fixed it.  In control panel>windows defender>options>real-time protection then uncheck scan downloaded files and attachments. After I did this, I could see images on my system use while creating an html page."

link to refer:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/some-pictures-have-been-blocked-to-helpactually/2aa402d3-0404-44d9-83ce-960258979c07